# How to get bind date from Vue Material DatePicker?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker

Probably a basic question, but I'm just beginning to learn Vue/Javascript in general.

I have a basic DatePicker component DatePicker.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <md-datepicker v-model="selectedDate">
      <label>Select date</label>
    </md-datepicker>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";

export default Vue.extend( {
  name: "LabeledDatepicker",
  data: () => ({
    selectedDate: null,
  }),
});
</script>
```

This component is used in a view like so:

```
<template>
   <div class="date-picker">
     <DatePicker />
   </div>
</template>
```

In my script I have two properties called fromDate and toDate which I want to get from two datepickers in my component.

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import DatePicker from "./DatePicker.vue";
export default Vue.extend({
  components: {
    DatePicker,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      fromDate: null,
      toDate: null,
    };
```

How do I bind the values selected in the datepickers to fromDate and toDate so I can use them in my API requests? I have tried to use v-model="fromDate", but fromDate was still null even after I selected a date.

Answer (score 0):

Your datepicker component needs to accept props if you want to both populate the value with existing values and update it from within the component. Alternatively, use "emit" from your datepicker component and then attach a method to handle change [custom event in Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names)